# It is possible to integrate identity core in an asp mvc 5 project?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, .net-framework-version

Right now i'm working on a enterprise project that is migratin from .net to .net core, and we successfully migrate ef 6 to ef core 2.1 in the project. We are not implementing identity yet in the project and we want to try identity core because we have ef core now in our project. It is possible to do so? or should we use the identity that comes whit the asp mvc 5 project.

Comment: I think you just follow the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio just follow the first four bullet points

Answer (score 0):

You are not specific enough unfortunately but I do not see a significant issue when migrating to Asp.Net Identity Core. The api became more fluid as of now. Perhaps the major change is that by default ASP.NET Identity templates do not include roles but you can add them easily.
Currently, you have three default options to add identity that is done via extension methods.

```
AddIdentity<TUser,Trole>
AddIdentityCore<TUser> (no cookies, no sign-in manager)
AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>
```

I would not recommend going with `AddDefaultIdentity` as it is bundled with a predefined bootstrap UI in a dll class library and even if you can use scaffolding to recover the code, there will be some code changes and bugs that you might encounter as of today not mentioning that you might need internationalization.
Also notice that the templates use Razor Pages instead of traditional MVC. That is actually a plus in my opinion security wise as antiforgery is backed-in and the code is simpler. In any case you will be able to translate code from razor pages to traditional mvc, so that shouldn't be an issue in my opinion.